# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'

Tags: oracle, excel, exception, odbc, oracle10g

i am uploading keywords into the DB. but i am getting the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6998)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7155)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3106)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:355)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:209)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:539)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:211)
    at keywordsreader.main(keywordsreader.java:28)
```

how to reslove this type error...plz help me..

**edit - additional info regarding architecture extracted from comment**

i am uploading the keywords from the excel file...for this i created a odbc driver for excel and i given the path of the excel... for past 15 min back...the keywords are uploaded properly..but i am geeting this error in this time..

Comment: You say you're using an Oracle database, but the error you're getting indicates you're using an ODBC driver for Microsoft Excel.  When connecting to an Oracle database you should be using an Oracle driver.  Check your ODBC data source and verify that you've specified that it should use an Oracle database driver.

Answer (score 0):

> i am uploading keywords into the DB.
>   but i am getting the error

How are you loading these keywords?  It obviously isn't one of the accepted ways (SQL Loader, external tables from a delimited file).  The details will matter here, because it looks like you have a bug in your code or your architecture.  The more information you provide, the more likely it is you will get a happy outcoem.

**edit**

Still not enough information.  Obviously there is some contention between your EXcel ODBC and the some other process running ODBC.   If as you say ...

> the keywords are uploaded properly

... then my advice is to forget about it.  However, if you really want us to help solve this problem ...

> but i am geeting this error in this
>   time

... you are going to have to explain your architecture and process in greater detail.

The choice is yours.

Comment: i am uploading the keywords from the excel file...for this i created a odbc driver for excel and i given the path of the excel...

for past 15 min back...the keywords are uploaded properly..but i am geeting this error in this time...